# Share a link via URL scheme to Discord

Tags: ios, discord

I want to Share a link via URL scheme to Discord

I'm able to open Discord app using "discord://"

However I need a way to mimic the same behaviour when I tap on native share sheet where Discord is opened with share in/ share to window, like what's appearing in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like not any solutions found. The share sheet possibly implemented by discord app via share extension, and the URL link can only open discord app directly.

Comment: Are you saying there's no way to achieve what the asker said?